# Unity how to get position from objects that has collided with another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, collider

Currently im trying to get a T square to lock its position with lines that i have created but im not sure how to get the x position of a line. And right now my T square is able to detect thats it colliding with the lines. Heres my current code.

```
void LockPostion(float x)
{
    gObjTmp.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Lines") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Collision with line");
        LockPostion (minlockXPos);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you used `this.transform.position` to get the position of `this` Object the script is attached to, `col.transform.position` should be used to get the position of the other Object returned from the collision function or  `col.transform.position.x` just for the `x` axis.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Lines")
    {
        Vector3 linePos = col.transform.position;
        float linePosX = col.transform.position.x;

        Debug.Log("Collision with line");
        LockPostion(linePosX);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, i didn know it can used that way too. Thks